# ElasticsearchTemplate - why implicit indexName for some operations and explicit for others

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Looking at the API of ElasticsearchTemplate, some operations **take the `indexName` explicitly** - for example: 
`public String delete(String indexName, String type, String id) {...}`
Other API operations do not - for example, **`queryForObject`**:  
`public <T> T queryForObject(GetQuery query, Class<T> clazz) {`
What this means is that - using `queryForObject` - *there's no way to run that operation against a specific index*.

My questions is - first - am I missing something? If not - is there a reason why the index name is not an input for all the API operations?
Cheers, 
Eugen.

Comment: Your questions are not very clear, can you make the effort on rewriting them so we can try to help!

Comment: I added an example to my question - hope that's clearer now, but if not, please do let me know and I'll go into the issue a bit more. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's because methods/operations that take a `Class` as a parameter use the Elasticsearch mapping of that `Class` to determine the index and type to operate on.  When you write your `Class` whose instances you're going to store in Elasticsearch, you give it a `@Document` annotation which specifies the ES index and type that's going to hold JSON translations of the `Class`-es instances.